# How to fix error in this b-tree code while deleting node

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, b-tree

I am using code from below url to implement btree data structure but getting core dump error in code sometimes while deleting key.
How can I fix error in this code?

https://github.com/khalibartan/Data-structure-codes-in-C/blob/master/Codes/btree.c

```
I have changed doRightshift function which cause for core dump error
void doRightShift(struct btreeNode *myNode, int pos) {
    struct btreeNode *x = myNode->link[pos];
    int j = x->count;
    while (j > 0) {
            x->val[j + 1] = x->val[j];
            x->link[j + 1] = x->link[j];
            j--;
}

but still sometimes getting problem of deleting multiple values instead of one
```

Comment: is it possible count+1 which j+1 later is crossing boundary for val and link array?